# how to resolve this issue "the type or namespace name 'service' could not be found" in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I am working on a project of c# using Visual Studio 2010, in which I need to get running services of a system by `ServiceController[] scServices = ServiceController.GetServices()` and now need to manipulate their result, there I need these objects help, but whenever I am declaring it's showing `"the type or namespace name 'Service' could not be found"`, I have added reference and `using System.ServiceProcess`.

```
Service rSvc = new Service();     
List<Service> rSvcList = new List<Service>();  
ListServicesReply rReply = new ListServicesReply();
```

Can somebody help me out, how to get rid of this?

Comment: you need to add reference if it is a web service add Service reference if its another project add dll reference

Comment: Are you *sure* this has not been asked before?

Comment: i have searched a lot but couldn't find.. similar but there is chances that i may not able to relate because i am new to this language @O.R.Mapper

Comment: Where does 'service' come from?

Comment: Are you sure `service` is spelled with a lower `s` in your error message?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It's not web service and i have added reference by going project->add reference->.Net->System.ServiceProcess

Comment: try with fully qualified name like ``System.ServiceProcess.Service obj``

Comment: @ZoolWay Sorry it's "Service"

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it's not helping.

Comment: when you write System.ServiceProcess see using intellisense is there any class with Service name?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, there could be two possible reasons for this error.

1. In your application you have a namespace = Service.
   In that case, compiler finds it ambiguous to resolve 'Service'. As suggested in some comments, using fully qualified namespace would help.
2. There is dependent assembly reference missing in your project. In this case, running msbuild with more logging would help. You can use following command from Visual Studio command prompt ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) reference)

   msbuild /verbosity:detailed yourpath/yourSolution.sln

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will work if you add reference to your project and `using System.ServiceProcess;`

There is no class in [System.ServiceProcess namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) called **Service**. **ListServicesReply** doesn't exist in the namespace either.

I think you copied a source code from a project which had defined **Service** and **ListServicesReply** on its own. I suggest you to go to the project you get the code from and search for the classes' definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The Service class is in the System.Web.Services namespace. It looks like you are working with regular Windows Services. If you are trying to manipulate a service, you can just use the ServiceController class.

```
    ServiceController[] scServices = ServiceController.GetServices();

    var myService = scServices.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DisplayName == "MyService");
    if (myService != null)
    {
        // do whatever with the service
        myService.Stop();
    }
```

If you are trying to create a service, you do so by inheriting from ServiceBase.

```
    public class MyService : ServiceBase
    {
        public MyService()
        {
            // configure the service
            this.ServiceName = "MyService";
        }

        // override the events you want
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }
    }
```